# How to add icons to titles in navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

How can we change the default camera,gallery etc. icons in navigation drawer ?I tried changing in the `activity_main_drawer.xml` from 
           `<item
            android:id="@+id/history"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="History" />`

to 
            `<item
            android:id="@+id/history"
            android:icon="@drawable/history"
            android:title="History" />`
But this doesn't work.It shows me a black square icon in its place . How to change that ? 
[image][image]

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of the issue?

Comment: I just need to know how can we change the default icons that are adjacent to titles in navigation drawer ?

Comment: I do it this way in Xamarin: `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view_menu">
    <group>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_white_24dp"
            android:title="@string/home" />
 </group>
</menu>`

Comment: That's a menu that contains a group in which there's a single item with home icon (from resources)

Comment: Doesn't work! A black square icon is being shown inplace .

Comment: That code should work, if it doesn't then error lies somewhere else... wondering what went wrong....

Comment: I've posted the snapshots.Maybe, this could help !

Comment: What is format of drawable file?

Comment: .png! Does that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon is colored semi transparent black when not active and primary color when selected. This is a feature. Use shape and transaprency to convey meaning, similar to notification icon.

This is a good example:

[image: Good example]

This is a bad example:

[image: Bad example]

Seeing from the preview your icons have solid white background instead of transparent.

Comment: How to do that ? conveying shape and transparency ?

Comment: Look at the example. One has just one color and transparent background. Use an image like that.